# jquery onchange of select option cannot display tbody tag

Tags: jquery

//select option show me values 1 to 12

```
<select name="damamonth" id="da" required>
    <option value="">--Months--</option>
    <option value=1 id=1>January</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">February</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">March</option>
    <option value="4" id="4">April</option>
    <option value="5" id="5">May</option>
    <option value="6" id="6">June</option>
    <option value="7" id="7">July</option>
    <option value="8" id="8">August</option>
    <option value="9" id="9">September</option>
    <option value="10" id="10">October</option>
    <option value="11" id="11">November</option>
    <option value="12" id="12">December</option>
</select>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Seq</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
```

// creating tbody for and display 1 to 12

```
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        <tbody id="@i" class="comsut" style="display:grid;">
            <tr style="border:1px;">
                <td>@i</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

// this script is not working for me, i am trying to display when i change the select option 
// according i display the tbody

```
<script>
 $(function () {
        $('.comsut').hide();
        $('#da').change(function () {
            var d = $(this).val();
            $('.comsut').hide();
            var ty = '#' + d;
            $(ty).show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create multiple `tbody`. create single `tbody` and multiple `tr`. Assigne `id` to `tr` and then run your script to show / hide them . See below code

```
<tbody >
@for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
            <tr id="@i" class="comsut" style="display:grid;border:1px;">
                <td>@i</td>
            </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
 $(function () {
        $('.comsut').hide();
        $('#da').change(function () {
            var d = $(this).val();
            $('tr.comsut').hide();
            var ty = '#' + d;
            $(ty).show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

Replace for loop with below

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        <tbody id="@i-t" class="comsut" style="display:grid;">
            <tr style="border:1px;">
                <td>@i</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    }
```

& script with following

```
<script>
 $(function () {
        $('.comsut').hide();
        $('#da').change(function () {
            var d = $(this).val();
            $('.comsut').hide();
            var ty = '#' + d + '-t';
            $(ty).show();
        });
    });

</script>
```